# triggering windows 10 onscreen keyboard in web site

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, keyboard

I have a javascript app that in the past used the javascript virtual keyboard - which works, but it's a bit small and ugly.

Tried it on a windows surface studio 2 device - and every time I touch an input box, not one but two keyboards come up... our one, and apparently some built in windows or chrome one - that takes the bottom half of the screen and *does* look nice.

That's great - that's the one I want to use.   So turn off my code that opens the javascript virtual keyboard.

and suddenly I get no keyboard at all when I touch an inputbox?

**So the question - does anyone know how to force the default windows 10 on screen keyboard to come up when an input box gets focus?**   It must be possible, because somehow calling the virtual keyboard functions causes it to happen.  For extra credit - one of my boxes is numeric - does anyone know how to force it to open the numeric keyboard instead of the standard one?

Comment: just curious, does the behavior change when you toggle the Windows 10 setting of whether or not it automatically shows the touch keyboard, ie: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-10-show-touch-keyboard-automatically

Comment: no it doesn't :(

Comment: a while back i tried to use my surface in desktop mode and I remember having issues with getting the behavior of when it triggers the onscreen keyboard to agree with me. I've since stopped using it so I don't know if Windows 10 settings have improved between then and now. What code triggers the js virtual keyboard? I'm not familiar with that

Comment: it's a library - called "Virtual Keyboard" - https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/   we use it, and it's fine - but it's not ok to get _two_ virtual keyboards popping up - one from windows (or chrome, not sure) - and one of ours.